# ionic 2 global variable

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a function, and in this function I have:

```
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then((localisation,err) => {

        this.storage.get('param1').then((param1) => {

            this.storage.get('param2').then((param2) => {
            // Do some stuff with localisation, param1 & param2
            alert(localisation);
            alert(param1);
            alert(param2);              
            })

        })
    })
```

That's the only way i found to use "localisation", "param1" & "param2" in the same time, if i do something like:

```
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then((localisation,err) => {
    })  
    this.storage.get('param1').then((param1) => {
    })              
    this.storage.get('param2').then((param2) => {
        // Do some stuff with localisation, param1 & param2
        alert(localisation);
        alert(param1);
        alert(param2);      
    })
```

It will not find localisation and param1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) here since the params are not interdependant. `Promise.all` takes in an array of promises and waits till all the promises return before executing the `then`.

```
let lPromise  =this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions);
let p1Promise = this.storage.get('param1');
let p2Promise =  this.storage.get('param2');
Promise.all([lPromise,p1Promise,p2Promise])
.then((values) => {
        // Do some stuff with localisation, param1 & param2
        alert(values[0]);//localization
        alert(values[1]);//param1
        alert(values[2]);//param2    
    })
```

Comment: glad to hear it :)